# How to implement a REST API base servlets and Tomcat8 with Spring/Hibernate

Tags: rest, servlets

i am new all around REST API and Servlets and i need to implement a Web application which get as a Host,User,Password and receiving the messages from the inbox mail list and print them.

i am looking for a good example how to do that or an example that demonstrate this
there is a good place for tutorials to learn it?

Comment: surely there are a lot of tutorials, you should make some research by yourself and then come back with some concrete question. Look at Spring website for tutorials

Comment: @matant If the tutorial is a good example, you should upvote the answer which i gave you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use Apache CXF or SpringFramework REST services. [This](https://github.com/nenov-nikola/java-restful-api) here is perfect example how to do this.